# Game of Life - Dead

Tags: c#, xna, logic

I was bored and had only 30 minutes of free time so I decided to have a crack at making the game of life. I followed that rules on wikipedia and it doesn't seem to be working correctly. Could someone please tell me what I would be doing wrong?

Here are the rules:
Any live cell with fewer than two live neighbours dies, as if caused by under-population.

Any live cell with two or three live neighbours lives on to the next generation.

Any live cell with more than three live neighbours dies, as if by overcrowding.

Any dead cell with exactly three live neighbours becomes a live cell, as if by reproduction.

```
public void PerformLogic()
{
    if (in_game)
    {
        time_elapsed += rate;

        if (time_elapsed > frame_rate)
        {
            time_elapsed = 0;

            for (int x = 0; x < board_width; x++)
            {
                for (int y = 0; y < board_height; y++)
                {
                    if (board[x, y] == alive)
                    {
                        int surrounding_cells = 0;

                        for (int x2 = -1; x2 <= 1; x2++)
                        {
                            for (int y2 = -1; y2 <= 1; y2++)
                            {

                                if (!(x2 + x <= -1 || y2 + y <= -1 || x + x2 >= board_width || y + y2 >= board_height))
                                {
                                    if (board[x + x2, y + y2] == alive)
                                    {
                                        surrounding_cells++;
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }

                        if (surrounding_cells < 2)
                        {
                            board[x, y] = dead;
                        }
                        if (surrounding_cells == 2 ||
                            surrounding_cells == 3)
                        {
                            board[x, y] = alive;
                        }
                        if (surrounding_cells > 3)
                        {
                            board[x, y] = dead;
                        }
                    }
                    else if (board[x, y] == dead)
                    {
                        int surrounding_cells = 0;

                        for (int x2 = -1; x2 <= 1; x2++)
                        {
                            for (int y2 = -1; y2 <= ; y2++)
                            {

                                if (!(x2 + x <= -1 || y2 + y <= -1 || x + x2 >= board_width || y + y2 >= board_height))
                                {                                        
                                    if (board[x + x2, y + y2] == alive)
                                    {
                                        surrounding_cells++;
                                    }
                                }

                            }
                        }

                        if (surrounding_cells == 3)
                        {
                            board[x, y] = alive;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: define "doesn't seem to be working correctly"? in what way does the behaviour not agree with your expectations?

Comment: "it doesn't seem to be working correctly" - A good example of a bad stack overflow question ;) What isn't working correctly? Be specific.

Comment: My God, split that code in smaller functions please!

Comment: hehe, good idea ;) Not very modular D:

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you are updating the board too early. The game of life should update the board after  it finishes scanning the whole board, rather than while scanning.

E.g.:

```
if (surrounding_cells > 3)
{
   board[x, y] = dead;
}
```

After this, for the cell next to it, this cell would be treated as dead.

Marc is right, too.

Comment: Exactly this killed my first attempt. :) Nice catch!

Comment: Thanks! Both of these answers helped immensely! And what a quick reply too :)

Answer (score 4):

```
for (int x2 = -1; x2 <= 1; x2++)
{
    for (int y2 = -1; y2 <= 1; y2++)
    {
```

looks to me like you're including the central cell in this loop, so 9 instead of 8.

I'm not sure the nested `for` is the best option, but if you are using that, add:

```
if(x2 == 0 && y2 == 0) continue;
```

at the start of the inner loop (i.e. after the last line that I've posted above)

Comment: this is *in addition* to updating the current grid, rather than having an old grid and a new grid (per Ziyao)

Comment: Thanks! Both of these answers helped immensely! And what a quick reply too :)